# can any one please explain how to build rpm for fedora10 linux

Tags: java, rpm

I have created an application in java. I have tried to create rpm file for that application. But I did not found what is the error. When I am creating rpm file i received an error No file or directory found.

http://javaworkshop.wordpress.com/

can any one please explain how to build rpm for fedora10 linux

My application (which is a simple Swing application) is installer.tar.gz

```
installer.spec
---------------
Name: installer
Summary:  The foo package does foo
Version :1
Release: 1
License: GPL
Group: Applications/Internet
URL: http://www.example.org/
Source0: %{name}.tar.gz
Buildroot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-root

%description 
This package performs the foo operation.
%prep 
%setup -q

%build 
%confifure

make

%install 
rm -fr %{buildroot}

%makeinstall

%clean 
rm -fr %{buildroot}
%changelog 


----------------------
```

If I run rpmbuild -ba ~/rpm/SPECS/installer.spec
then i found "No file or directory found error"

Thanks
Sunil KUmar Sahoo

Comment: please post some code so that we can help.

Comment: akf: No use, we've suggested that to this person before but apparently he just drops in to ask something and expects others to do his work for him.

Comment: Hi Esko. But As you mentioned that I want others to do my task. Its absolutely wrong. I am in a roadblock to build rpm file for my project If my motto is to get work done by you then i sholud not try. I think either this problem is very common for you or you are a person who wants to discourage others.

Comment: Does the file actually exist?

Comment: No that file does not exist. In the documentation of creating RPM there is no comments to create configure file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you created the SPEC file for your package?

It should be there before you call `rpmdev-setuptree` and `rpmbuild -bb --clean myprogram.spec`

You can read more about SPEC files and rpm building in [Fedora Developer's Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/developers-guide/ch-rpm-building.html).

Comment: I have created simple swing application in java and created jar file then created my SPEC file then I called rpmbuild -bb --clean myprogram.spec  . Here I got a problem "./configure No such file founf error"

Comment: Is there a configuration script `./configure` in your directory?

Comment: No in my directory there is no ./configure file. Also I donot know how to create and what should be the content

Comment: Obviously, you don't need it - because you provide already compiled into a jar file.

But look - what's that in your SPEC file:

    %build 
    %confifure
    make

Those lines are there to describe, how your code should be *compiled*! 

You should really _write_ your own SPEC file, not copypaste unsuitable one from the guide.

And yes, accepting my answer will be pleasant for me.

Comment: 2Sunil Kumar Sahoo Thanks. Have you succeed to build your package?

Comment: No am unable to build. Can ypu please guide me with step by step approach how to create rpm file for my simple java application.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I succeed to create RPM file